# AlamofireImageで取得した画像をそのままのサイズで表示したい。

Tags: swift, ios, alamofire

AlamofireImageの`af_setImageWithURL`で画像を動的に取得して表示させたいのですが、取得する画像のサイズに応じてUIImageViewのサイズを変えて取得したそのままの大きさで表示させたいです。このようなことは実現可能なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

取得した画像をmyImage(UIImage型)と仮定すると

```
let myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, (myImage?.size.width)!, (myImage?.size.height)!))
myImageView.image = myImage
```

というコードを書けばUIImageViewの大きさは画像の大きさになると思います。
必要としている答えと違ったら申し訳ないです。